# 12.04 precise HDMI not working on ATI Radeon

Tags: ati, radeon, hdmi

This is precisely a 12.04 HDMI output problem, because it works for 11.10 - everything else are the same, only the OS version is different.

The symptom is that on my HDMI output TV screen, it always shows **Unsupported resolution** even after setting it to the resolution that works on Ubuntu 11.10 (via gnome-control-center, in which it detects my TV just fine), I still don't see any output on TV.

The audio is not working either.

I think it is 12.04's problem, because if I boot into Ubuntu 11.10, and everything else remain the same, HDMI output (video & audio) work just fine.

12.04 is a freshly installed, just the vanilla Ubuntu HD installation.

How should I nailed down / fix the problem?

Comment: From http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11946650&postcount=27
"HDMI out works flawlessly on ATI cards with the fglrx driver installed rather than the open source one." 
  
Seem he has problem with the open source Radeon driver too, and find the fglrx driver to be the solution. But since Radeon has been working for me since 11.10, I want to avoid fglrx as much as possible.  
  
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried setting the resolution with catalyst control center?

Comment: Same I'm getting it on a HP 2309m monitor from the HDMI, change to the DVI all ok.
Disappointed.
The screeen is diplaying 1 inch inside the boarder of the monitor on HDMI

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem on my Samsung FullHD-tv that the tv showed me every time "Unsupported Resolution" under the 1080p mode, but when I switched to 1080i (1920*1080*30Hz) all worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try upgrading to a newer version of ubuntu with the following:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Updating might allow you to receive updates that are not available on such an old version of ubuntu. The issue might be fixed on Ubuntu 14.04 (Although I recommend you upgrade to at least Ubuntu 18.04).